# Cannot use regex with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regex to wrap `table` tags in a string with a span:

```
str.replace(<\s*table[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*table>, '<span>$1</span>')
```

Yet my javascript won't compile.

Why?

Comment: Your regex is not valid. Test it on https://regex101.com/
Regex at JS needs to start and end with `/`. Or create a `RegExp` object.

Answer (score 2):

- `<` is the less-than operator, not the begining of a regular expression literal, which are delimited with `/` characters.
- The first character after the `<` in an HTML tag cannot be white space so matching it doesn't make sense.
- `/` characters, since they delimit the regex, must be escaped

Such:

```
str.replace(/<table[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>/, '<span>$1</span>')
```

However:

Your capturing group is around the **content** of a table element, not around the whole element, so this will change `<table>...</table>` into `<span>...</span>` and not `<span><table>...</table></span>`.

… but **both** of those would be **invalid HTML** since nothing that can be a child of a `<table>` element can be a child of a `<span>` element, and not can a `<table>` element.

Comment: Thanks, still can't compile though, erroring on first backslash before s

Answer (score -1):

## command

```js
'<table>Hello There</table>'.replace(/<\s*table[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*table>/, '<span>$1</span>')
```

## output

```html
<span>Hello There</span>
```